# Matplotlib: Forcing contour labels within image limits

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pickled matplotlib figure with labeled contours
[image]

After loading the pickle, If I change the x limits/y limits of the image (as seen below), the clabels seem to disappear for most part of the plot.

[image]

Any ideas how to force the clabels back into the image limits.?
I was unable to find any help within the matplotlib documentation or on Google.

Comment: The clabels are placed at positions inside the area of the contours. This is independent on the view- or axes limits. In order for the labels to appear in the region of interest, one would need to plot a contour plot which is limited to this region.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you! I figured that out

Comment: ...as well and I'm re-plotting the contours